# How do I delete duplicate rows in sqlite where every column including the ID is dupplicate?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite. I am importing a dataset where the ID is assigned externally into a temporary table before I insert them into my permanent table. Permanent table uses the external id (RunId) and has no other id column.

I import the table from csv into a new table Book1 where C15 is the ID column. Then the I run the insert:

```
INSERT INTO PrimusRuns (RunId, TransientName, RunDateStart, RunType, TestDateStart,
                    Gross, CPS, Shares, MaxExposure, PercentWin, Duration)
SELECT a.C15, a.C1, JULIANDAY(a.C2), a.C3,JULIANDAY(a.C4),
        a.C6, a.C8, a.C9, a.C10, a.C11, a.C14
FROM Book1 as a;
```

however I get a primary key constraint error:

```
[19] [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY] A PRIMARY KEY constraint failed (UNIQUE constraint failed: PrimusRuns.RunID)
```

First I thought some of these rows are already in the table however running:

```
SELECT * FROM Book1 WHERE C15 IN(
  SELECT RunID from PrimusRuns
);
```

returns nothing.

Then I realized there are duplicate rows in the import when I ran:

```
SELECT * FROM Book1 GROUP BY C15 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This aggregate query return 95 rows meaning there's at least 95 rows I must delete. How to I delete tell it to delete the duplicates?

NOTE : There are other questions similar to this, however my question is different in that the id is also a duplicate. Other questions group all the rest of the column and delete the max(id). But in my case max id returns both rows not just one.

Comment: @CL already explained why this is not a dupplicate

Comment: The rowid is not your ID.

Comment: suggested solutions do not work because max(id) and min(id) return both rows

Comment: The linked answers do not use `min(id)` but `min(rowid)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what  is related only at the deletion of the duplicated row reffering to C15 you could find all the min(id) group by C15  .. so this are the single row for each C15 value
and the delete the others eg

```
  delete from 
  book1
  where id not in ( 
  select min(id)
  from Book1
  group by C15)
```

but if you have a full exactly duplicated  rows you could  do useìin these steps  ..

1 ) You can create a temporary table with the distinct result for duplicated  eg:

```
create table my_temp_distinct  as  
select col1, col2 ... 
from Book1
group by col1, col2, ... 
having count(*)> 1
```

2 ) then delete all  the rows with duplicated  rows

```
  delete from 
  book1
  where id in ( 
  select min(id)
  from Book1
  group by C15)
```

3 ) and last insert using select form the parked  rows

```
insert into Book1 (col1, col2 ....)
select col1, col2, ...
from my_temp_distinct
```

Comment: ids for both duplcate rows are the same

Comment: have you some others column for avoid a full duplicated  rows  or not?

Comment: no, the entire row is fully duplicated

Comment: ok  ... just a few minutes

Comment: Answer updated  hope is useful

Comment: worked thanks, i had to make a few edits in your code, please accept them

Comment: Ok  ..updated accepted ...  many thanks for the  corrections